# Upload a file and handle redirection [PYTHON]

Tags: python, post, python-requests, qr-code

I need to submit an image to the site https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, and read the result page : https://zxing.org/w/decode.

I tried this, but it does not work :

```
def decode_qrcode(path):
    s = requests.Session()

    url = "https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx"
    files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
    s.post(url, files=files)
    return s.get("https://zxing.org/w/decode").text
```

I know that there are librairies to read QR code, but I did not find any that works for the kind of QR codes that I work with (they might have an error rate not supported).

Comment: Please try to be a little more specific. What exactly 'does not work'? Are you receiving an error, then please post the full Traceback. Or is your output not what you expect? Then you may post the output you get along with the output you expect.

Comment: When I do a post request with either an url (see option 1 below) or a file (see option 2 below) and display the text, it seems that the site did not considered the url or file...
And when I do a get request to display the content of the supposed result page, it says that I did not provide anything.

Option 1 : https://pastebin.com/EqMxU53z

Comment: The other result (option 1) : https://pastebin.com/30HzBWV3
And for option 2 : https://pastebin.com/tbNqfbbA

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `allow_redirects` argument when making the `POST` request

```
import requests
def decode_qrcode(path):
    s = requests.Session()

    url = "https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx"
    files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
    s.post(url, files=files, allow_redirects = True)
    return s.get("https://zxing.org/w/decode").text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Just tried it but it does not work too... I get this :

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/><title>Bad URL</title><link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body><div id="main"><div id="header"><h1><img alt="" id="icon" src="zxing-icon.png"/>&nbsp;Bad URL</h1></div><p>You didn't specify a URL, or the URL was not valid, or did not return an image. Go "Back" in your browser and try again.</p></div></body></html>

As if it did not accept the file...

Comment: @Lcram33 that means that the issue is with the URL not with the code.