# Python requests: upload a file and subsequently parse data from a redirection

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I'm trying to convert a PDB (Protein DataBank format) file into a SMILES string (representation of a molecule) using this online converter: https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/translate/

When you submit a PDB file and press the "translate" button it redirects to a new url with the SMILES string. How can I parse the output SMILES string from the redirected url using requests? All the options can stay default. What I've tried so far:

```
import requests

url='https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/translate/'

with open("MTK.pdb", "rb") as file:
    pdbfile = {'pdb': file}
    r = requests.post(url, files=pdbfile, allow_redirects=True)
```

But it just keeps giving me the main page. Thanks in advance.

Possible duplicate of: [Upload a file and handle redirection [PYTHON]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901582/upload-a-file-and-handle-redirection-python)

edit: pdb file in question: https://pastebin.com/zBNtqR7K (save as .pdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You post to the error url,and post it in an error way.

The file from the form called `file`.And don't forget to add some extra parameters in the `data`.Or it will receive 500,

```
import requests

url = 'https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/cgi-bin/translate.tcl'

with open(r"xxx.pdb", "rb") as file:
    pdbfile = {'file': file}
    data = {
        "smiles":"C12C3C4C1C5C4C3C25",
        "format": "screen",
        "astyle": "kekule",
        "dim":"2D"
    }
    r = requests.post(url, files=pdbfile, data=data)
    print(r.text)
```

Result:

```
....
<FONT STYLE="Helvetica, Arial">
<B>CC(C)(O)C1=C(CCC(SCC2(CC2)CC(O)=O)C3=CC(=CC=C3)CCC4=NC5=CC(=CC=C5C=C4)Cl)C=CC=C1</B>
</FONT>
...
```